# Pass html to an index template and save into a javascript variable with nodejs and hoganjs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have hongajs in my nodejs app, and I need to pass an html content to an variable into my index.html file so, I try with this.

I have on nodejs this fragment:

```
 res.render('index.html',{
                    note:{
                        title: doc.title,
                        body: doc.body
                    }
                });
```

And in my index.html this:

```
 <script>
    var parseNote = '{{note.body}}';
</script>
```

Of corse I tryed with {{{ and JSON.stringify, and many other javascript function, but any seems to work.

Some ideas?

Comment: maybe it works with only one level and not nested object ?

Comment: I try with that.. note.body is an html, but the problem seems to be the especial caractecters into the note.body element.